# How to determine if a user is an administrator from an unprivileged application with Win32?

Tags: windows, winapi, administrator, elevated-privileges

From an unprivileged application I want to run a privileged application. But I want to check if the user is a administrator BEFORE launching the application.

Win32 provides `IsUserAnAdmin()` and `IsUserAdmin()` but both of these will return `0` if called from an unprivileged process. This is because what it's really doing is asking whether the process has administrative access rather if the user is a member of the \Administrators group.

Is it possible to determine if the user is part of the administrators group from an unpriviledged process?

There are a few questions similar to this already but this is NOT a duplicate. Specifically, I want to know if the USER is part of the group not whether the PROCESS has inherited administrative permissions; and if it can be done with Win32 (not .NET).

Comment: `NetUserGetLocalGroups()` maybe.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a handle to the users token (from `OpenProcessToken` etc.) you can perform the classic admin check that ignores "for deny only" groups: Call `GetTokenInformation(..., TokenGroups, ...)` and look for the administrators group SID.

If you only have a username/SID you can use [NetUserGetLocalGroups](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370655(v=vs.85).aspx) or `NetLocalGroupGetMembers`.

Answer (score 1):

you need first of all check your token [`TOKEN_ELEVATION_TYPE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb530718(v=vs.85).aspx).

if you got *`TokenElevationTypeDefault`* or *`TokenElevationTypeFull`* - you can not elevate and maximum which you can have under this user account you already have in token. for query are token is admin or are you have some privileges - need query your current token as is.

if you got *`TokenElevationTypeLimited`* - you need query for linked token via [*`TokenLinkedToken`*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379626(v=vs.85).aspx) and check this linked token instead your current token - because after elevation privileged application will be use this token.

for example:

```
ULONG IsTokenAdmin(HANDLE hToken, PBOOL pbIsAdmin)
{
    ULONG cbSid = MAX_SID_SIZE;
    PSID pSid = alloca(cbSid);
    return CreateWellKnownSid(::WinBuiltinAdministratorsSid, 0, pSid, &cbSid) &&
        CheckTokenMembership(hToken, pSid, pbIsAdmin) ? NOERROR :  GetLastError();
}

ULONG IsUserAnAdminEx(PBOOL pbIsAdmin, PBOOL pbNeedElevate)
{
    ULONG dwError = NOERROR;

    HANDLE hToken;
    if (OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_QUERY|TOKEN_DUPLICATE, &hToken))
    {
        ULONG cb;
        union {
            TOKEN_ELEVATION_TYPE tet;
            TOKEN_LINKED_TOKEN tlt;
        };

        if (GetTokenInformation(hToken, ::TokenElevationType, &tet, sizeof(tet), &cb))
        {
            switch (tet)
            {
            case TokenElevationTypeLimited:
                *pbNeedElevate = TRUE;
                if (GetTokenInformation(hToken, ::TokenLinkedToken, &tlt, sizeof(tlt), &cb))
                {
                    dwError = IsTokenAdmin(tlt.LinkedToken, pbIsAdmin);
                    CloseHandle(tlt.LinkedToken);
                }
                else
                {
                    dwError = GetLastError();
                }
                break;
            case TokenElevationTypeFull:
            case TokenElevationTypeDefault:
                *pbNeedElevate = FALSE;
                // only because CheckTokenMembership want an impersonation token.
                // really most query can be and must be done direct with this token
                if (DuplicateToken(hToken, ::SecurityIdentification, &tlt.LinkedToken))
                {
                    dwError = IsTokenAdmin(tlt.LinkedToken, pbIsAdmin);
                    CloseHandle(tlt.LinkedToken);
                }
                else
                {
                    GetLastError();
                }
                break;
            default:
                dwError = ERROR_GEN_FAILURE;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            dwError = GetLastError();
        }

        CloseHandle(hToken);
    }

    return dwError;
}
```